# How to detect shared data service changes for all components in Angular 9?

Tags: angular, detection, angular-services

I´m doing an Angular Application with a custom library.
There are several nested components.

In a child component, I click on a button to set new data from a form.

```
<button ... (click)="createFile()" >Create file</button>
```

**child.component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="starterFormArray" *ngIf="starterFormWithStepper">
     <mat-horizontal-stepper #stepper>
         <mat-step *ngFor="let step of starterFormSteps; let index = index; let last = last;">
             <ng-template matStepLabel>{{ step.label }}</ng-template>
             <formly-form
                      [form]="starterFormArray.at(index)"
                      [model]="starterModel"
                      [fields]="step.fields"
                      [options]="starterOptions[index]">
              </formly-form>
         </mat-step>
     </mat-horizontal-stepper>
     <div class="wrapper-actions-for-stepper">
          <div class="part-toolbar">
              <button mat-stroked-button (click)="goBack(stepper)" type="button" [disabled]="stepper.selectedIndex === 0">Back</button>
              <button mat-stroked-button (click)="goForward(stepper)" type="button" [disabled]="stepper.selectedIndex === starterFormSteps.length-1">Next</button>
          </div>
          <div class="part-toolbar">
              <button mat-raised-button [disabled]="!starterFormArray.valid" (click)="createFile()" >Create file</button>
          </div>
      </div>
  </form>
```

The child component function `CreateFile()` set a var inside a shared data service

**child.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'foo-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss'],
  providers:  [ DataService, provideParent( ParentComponent, BaseComponent  ) ]
})

export class ChildComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked, AfterContentInit {

     starterForm: FormGroup;
     starterFormArray: FormArray;
     starterModel: CurrentProject;
     starterFormFields: Array<FormlyFieldConfig>;
     starterFormSteps: Array<StepType>;
     starterOptions: any;
     starterFormWithStepper: boolean;

     constructor(elRef: ElementRef, data: DataService ) {
         super(elRef);
         this.sharedData = data;
     }

     createFile() {
          this.sharedData.changeUserFile( this.starterModel );
     }
}
```

`sharedData` parameter is declared in `BaseComponent`.

**base.component.ts**

```
import {DataService} from '../../common/services/data.service';

export class BaseComponent{
    public sharedData: DataService;
}
```

In my shared service, I tried to do a way for any changes are detected for all components using it.

**data.service.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService{
    public file: BehaviorSubject<CurrentProject> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
    public changeFile = this.file.asObservable();
    
    constructor( public cdref: ChangeDetectorRef ) {}

    changeUserFile( newData: CurrentProject ){
        this.file.next(newData);
        alert(JSON.stringify( this.file.getValue())); //<-- it works !
        this.cdref.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

But `parent.component.ts` never detects changes.

**parent.component.ts**

```
@Component({
    selector: 'foo-parent',
    templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./parent.component.scss'],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
    providers:  [ DataService, provideParent( ParentComponent ) ]
})
export class ParentComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges{
      
     @Input() fileName: string;
      
      constructor(elRef: ElementRef, data: DataService, private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef ) {
           this.sharedData = data;
      }

      ngOnInit() {
          super.ngOnInit();
          this.sharedData.changeFile.subscribe( ( fileModified) => {
              if ( ( fileModified !== null ) && ( fileModified.getFileName() !== this.fileName ) ) {
                  alert('Never Called');
                  this.fileName = fileModified.getFileName();
              }
          }); 
      }
      ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
          alert('change only when the page is loaded');
      }
}
```

For some reasons, `parent.component.ts` cannot actualize data, `this.sharedData.changeFile.subscribe()` does not work.
I tested `ngOnChanges` and `ChangeDetectorRef`  without success.

Someone knows the issue ?

Comment: You are saying that you don't see any value emitted to the changeFile stream from the parent component subscription? Change detection is unrelated to your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Each component is another instance of a class. Extending does not make them share same values but services are instantiated once and same instance is acessed with injecting in the constructor everywhere within the scope of service module.

Simple solution would be to inject DataService and subscribe to it which would point to the same ref from everywhere in your app.

eg pseudo code:

## DataService

```
class DataService {
  public file: BehaviorSubject<CurrentProject> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  setDataMethod(newData: CurrentProject) {
    this.file.next(newData);
  }
}
```

### ParentComp

```
class ParentComp extends BaseComp implements OnInit{
   constructor(private (or public to access from html) dataService: DataService) {}
   
   ngOnInit(){
     this.dataService.file.subscribe(changedFile => {
        //do stuff
     })
   }
}
```

### Or any other related / not related child component within same module where DataService is in providers

```
class ParentComp extends BaseComp implements OnInit {
   constructor(private (or public to access from html) dataService: DataService) {}
   
   ngOnInit(){
     this.dataService.file.subscribe(changedFile => {
        //do stuff
     })
   }
}
```

Comment: Services can actually be instantiated multiple times. This could be related to the issue. 

https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services

Comment: @Eray Ismailov - I implemented your solution. I still have the dame problem. `this.dataService.file.subscribe()` is never called in `parent.component.ts`.

Comment: @J.BizMai please check this for more detailed explanation with example usage

https://codesandbox.io/s/shared-data-80pro?file=/src/app/app.module.ts

Comment: @Eray Ismailov - In your example, the data inserted comes from the parent and go to child component down. It works perfectly like this. In my case, the form and the button is in the child component and inserted values have to be visible in the parent component as well.

Comment: @ErayIsmailov, yes it´s true. I did it to check in : https://codesandbox.io/s/shared-data-forked-s50pu?file=/src/app/child/child.component.html